# Accessible HTML - tfoot usage

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I'm perpetually trying to wrap my head around the usage of `<tfoot>`, and which direction I should head for the most accessible approach.

`<tfoot>` is supposed to summarise the columns: in a perfect situation, every column has a corresponding summary cell in the `<tfoot>`.

Unfortunately, this is pretty much never the case.

Usually there are only a couple of columns that have numerical data, the others being text, and thus, unsummarisable.

The typical thing I've always done, and many seem to do, is have blank cells in the `<tfoot>`, as well as one cell that uses `colspan="<num>"` to provide a label saying **Total** or something similar.

Now, since the attribute `scope="col"` isn't being used, but rather `id=""`s with `headers=""`, a part of me thinks that even though that **Total** cell doesn't correspond to the two columns it is spanning, this is okay, because of the `headers`. However, is it really okay?

I'm not sure. I'm never sure. Part of me wants to insert one cell that spans all the columns, in order to insert a fresh table with only these three cells. That seems equally wrong.

Semantically, I think the best idea might be to take the Totals out of the table entirely, and have a `<dl>` with the Total text and the corresponding figures.

A clear insight would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y29wg/

```
<table class="table table-striped" summary="Transaction summary. There is 1 row of column headings.">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="transaction-type" class="cell-100">Transaction</th>
            <th id="transaction-team" class="cell-150">Country</th>
            <th id="transaction-credit" class="text-right cell-100">Credit Amount</th>
            <th id="transaction-debit" class="text-right cell-100">Debit Amount</th>
            <th id="transaction-status" class="cell-100">Status</th>
            <th id="transaction-progress" class="cell-100">Progress</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th id="transaction-total" colspan="2" class="text-right">Total</th>
            <td headers="transaction-total" class="text-right">$845.00</td>
            <td headers="transaction-total" class="text-right">$510.00</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td headers="transaction-type">Deposit</td>
            <td headers="transaction-team">n/a</td>
            <td headers="transaction-credit" class="text-right">$300.00</td>
            <td headers="transaction-debit" class="text-right">&#160;</td>
            <td headers="transaction-status">Deposited</td>
            <td headers="transaction-progress">Complete</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`tfoot` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element) is an optional part of a table, containing “column summaries (footers)”. This is rather vague, and `tfoot` is used rarely and inconsistently; even some W3C pages use it for copyright notices! Thus, there is little reason to expect any special accessibility benefits from using it. The only special treatment in browsers seems to be that some browsers may repeat the footer rows at the end of a page when a table is divided on two or more pages in printing.

In the example, the use of `tfoot` is OK by the definitions. It’s useful to have the totals in the same table as the detailed data, since the data belongs together and this is a common setup. Empty cells are a problem in principle, as it raises the questions “why is this cell empty? is it by mistake? what message does it convey?” But in a simple case like this, it’s OK; using a dash “–” or the abbreviation “N/A”, or using gray background, might make the situation a bit more obvious, but it might also confuse or disturb. There is no markup for telling that some cells are not “real”, i.e. do not (and could not) contain information matching the row and column headers.